# How can I change the directory a command thinks it is running in?

Tags: linux, crontab

How can I run a command that is in a different directory so that the command thinks I've ran it in the current directory?

If a command is using `basename()` or `argv[0]` (or whatever it's called) to get where it was called from, and it requires files in its directory, it may look in the directory that you called the application from; i.e. the wrong one.

Of course, you can `cd` to the directory first and invoke it there, but is there a way to invoke the application so that it thinks you've ran it from its directory (without `cd`ing first)?

If it is possible, I will use this in `crontab`, as the thought of using `cd` in there scares me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why does using `cd` in crontab scare you?

Note that if you want to just temporarily change directory and then come back, you can use `pushd` and `popd`

Comment: I get the impression it could affect the workings of other commands that may be in there, or the cron daemon? Maybe I'm being a bit daft, like.

Comment: And I suppose I'm not a fan of the strings of `cd dir && ./cmd` entries in the crontab. I just figured there would be a way to do it easily.

Comment: @panic This is actually the common way to do it. `cd blah && command`.

Comment: @panic Well, then use `pushd` and `popd`. `pushd dir && ./cmd && popd`

Answer (score 2):

You can make a script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /dir/
yourcommand
```

Then save it somewhere and add that script to crontab